# Get all running Docker containers whose image is derived from a specific image

Tags: docker

I have two Docker images, let's call them `base` and `derived`. As the names suggest, the one is `FROM`ed from the other.

Now, among other containers, I start multiple instances of `derived`.

How can I get a list of all of them? In other words: How can I identify containers whose image is derived from a specific base image?

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the dockerfile from image https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image that will get this information for you. Some scripting based on this and`docker ps`should do what you want.

Comment: Although I won't use the image you referred to, its description gives me some hints on how to proceed. Hence, thanks for this :-)

Answer (score -2):

Does this work for you?

```
sudo docker ps | grep base | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Ehm, no, it doesn't. `docker ps` just shows the `derived` images, not their ancestors.